# iOS GDFileManagerKit Do not show cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

In my project I use the [GDFileManagerKit](https://github.com/GrahamDennis/GDFileManagerKit) to select files from DropBox and Google Drive.
I open the File manager like this;

```
UIStoryboard *fileBrowserStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"FileBrowser"
                                                                bundle:[NSBundle   bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"GDFileManagerKit"
                                                                                                                       withExtension:@"bundle"]]
                                       ];
GDFileServiceSessionListController *serviceController = [fileBrowserStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:serviceController animated:YES];
```

The problem here is that when the view is pushed onto the stack I don't get a 'back' button on the top-left of the screen.

The code within GDFileManagerKit (GDFileServiceSessionListController.m: `viewDidLoad`)causing this is:

```
if ([self presentingViewController]) {
    // If we are being presented, then we should have a cancel button.
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelItem;
}
```

When I comment this `if` statement out I do see a back button. Is there a way to prevent the cancel button from showing, or to remove it when the controller renders it's view without hacking the GDFileManagerKit?